# what's the right process to debug with node-inspector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I'm on node version v5.0.0. I installed node-inspector version: v0.12.5.

**what I did:**
1st. I start node-insepctor on port 8090 (due to 8080 is taken by nginx)

```
node-insepctor --web-port=8090
```

2nd. I start debugging my js file

```
node --debug-brk app.js
```

3rd. I open the url in browser

```
http://127.0.0.1:8090/?ws=127.0.0.1:8090&port=5858
```

It works for the 1st time, it will perfectly break at the first line. But after I find and fix the issue in my code and I want to debug again, it just can't works again.

**What I tried:**

**1st**. 
I see that in the console, the following line which printed when I `node --debug-brk app.js` is still there:

```
Debugger listening on port 5858
```

So I refresh the page, the code is shown, but it just doesn't get executed, so no break point is reached.

**2nd**. I stop the app.js debug process by `CTRL-c`, and restart debugging app.js, `Debugger listening on port 5858` is shown again. so I open the url again. same as above, the code is shown, but nothing happens.

**3rd**. I stop both the node-inspector process and app.js debug process and restart them both and open the url. this time, it works!!

Is there an easy way to debug a js program more than once??
Every time I need to kill both node-inspector process and debug js process to make it work again??
Or I'm doing something wrong here??

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

`node-inspector` can be executed with the `node-debug <file>` command which adds the `--debug-brk` option by default. This opens the file in the *Sources* tab and breaks on the first line.

To continue debugging, you'll need to follow the steps below:

1. Select the file you need to debug from the *Sources* tab.
2. Click on a line number of the file to set a breakpoint.
3. Resume script execution (F8). This will cause the execution to break on the line that was highlighted in step 2.

Comment: thanks for the tip of using `node-debug`, it's much simpler now. But I still don't how to debug the second time, I still need to kill the `node-debug` process and restart again ?